# crosstool-NG can't retrieve cloog-ppl

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I am trying to build a cross-compiler for my Raspberry Pi to ultimately compile `ffmpeg` for it and I am following [this tutorial](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/RaspberryPi).

After having configured ct-ng and upon calling `nt-cg build` it fails and prints this:

```
[INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
[INFO ]  Build started 20150217.180740
[INFO ]  Building environment variables
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs
[ERROR]    Could not retrieve 'cloog-ppl-0.15.10'.
[00:31] / make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Taking a look into the `build.log` I find

```
...
[INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs
[DEBUG]    Already have 'linux-2.6.36'
[DEBUG]    Already have 'gmp-5.0.1'
[DEBUG]    Already have 'mpfr-3.0.0'
[DEBUG]    Already have 'ppl-0.11'
[EXTRA]    Retrieving 'cloog-ppl-0.15.10'
[DEBUG]    Trying 'ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10.tar.bz2'
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'curl -s --ftp-pasv -O --retry 3     ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10.tar.bz2 --connect-timeout 30 -L -f'
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'curl -s -O --retry 3 ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10.tar.bz2 --connect-timeout 30 -L -f'
[DEBUG]    Trying 'ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10.tar.gz'
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'curl -s --ftp-pasv -O --retry 3 ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10.tar.gz --connect-timeout 30 -L -f'
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'curl -s -O --retry 3 ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10.tar.gz --connect-timeout 30 -L -f'
[DEBUG]    Trying 'ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10.tgz'
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'curl -s --ftp-pasv -O --retry 3 ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10.tgz --connect-timeout 30 -L -f'
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'curl -s -O --retry 3 ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10.tgz --connect-timeout 30 -L -f'
[DEBUG]    Trying 'ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10.tar'
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'curl -s --ftp-pasv -O --retry 3 ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10.tar --connect-timeout 30 -L -f'
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'curl -s -O --retry 3 ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10.tar --connect-timeout 30 -L -f'
[DEBUG]    Trying 'ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10'
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'curl -s --ftp-pasv -O --retry 3 ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10 --connect-timeout 30 -L -f'
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'curl -s -O --retry 3 ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-ppl-0.15.10 --connect-timeout 30 -L -f'
[ERROR]    Could not retrieve 'cloog-ppl-0.15.10'.
```

Manually trying to fetch the file seems not to work because it is not available(?)

I have actually compiled the newest [CLooG](http://www.cloog.org/) but I don't know how to point nt-cg in the right direction.

Any help would be appreciated.